# Jquery gets empty value after appending a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I append a `<textarea>` with jquery and get as fallowing:

```
<textarea class="comment_textarea" placeholder="Comment on this post.." title="Comment on this post.." name="comment_here"></textarea>
```

when i try to run a function:

```
function makeComment(){
    var comment = $(this).val();
    console.log(comment);
}
$("#newsfeed_posts").bind('keyup', '.comment_textarea', makeComment);
```

i get a empty value on my console, i also try accessing different attributes from the textarea but i don't anything. Can someone help me get the value when i press on the keys and if possible when i specifically press enter?
 thank you in advance.

Comment: The 2nd argument for bind is expected to be an object that will be passed to the handler, not a selector. The listener will be set for `#newsfeed_posts` not for `.comment_textarea` . Use on as proposed by Frank Conry

Comment: Can you show how you're appending a textarea, because you've commented that event delegation is not necessary, and if you're appending after the initial page load, it is probably necessary.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.bind()` is old , `.on()` is current.

Comment: I just realize i am using the old version of jquery, i must of accidentally upload the wrong one to my host. that is why .on() is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use event delegation you might try:

```
$("body").on('keyup', '.comment_textarea', makeComment);
```

The binding may have occurred before the text area was part of the dom and this should get around it.

Comment: on is not a function, i believe it was removed from jquery so i cannot use it

Comment: @user2444411 you can and sometimes you must. Not nessesery here tho

Comment: @user2444411 .on most definately is a jQuery function

Comment: @user2444411: `on` has been introduced 2 years ago in jQuery 1.7 , you should consider an update of the jQuery-version

Comment: sorry i was using the wrong jquery you're right .on() is current .bind() is old. how would i check for a key event?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function makeComment(ele){
   return $(ele).val();
}

$("#newsfeed_posts").keyup(function(){
   var comment = makeComment('.comment_textarea');
   console.log(comment);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You used bind() with wrong syntax .

```
$(selector).bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler(eventObject) )
```

Others, If you want to use delegation , please use live ( old version of Jquery), on  (new version) or delegate()
Example

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", {
  msg: "Click message"
}, function( event ) {
  alert( event.data.msg );
});
```

In your case, i think you can use

```
 $(".comment_textarea").live('keyup', makeComment);
    $("#newsfeed_posts").on('keyup', '.comment_textarea', makeComment);
or  $("#newsfeed_posts").delegate('.comment_textarea','keyup', makeComment);
```

Hope it help you